# How to change alpha of uinavigation item

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

Now,when I clicked backbutton,the alpha of leftbarbutton item changed.
But I don't want to change alpha of leftbarbutton's arrow when I clicked backbutton.
I uploaded picture which alpha is changed when i clicked back button.
How can i realize?

[image]

Comment: Initialise the `UIBarButtonItem` with a `UIButton` as its custom view, and set the the button's `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` property to `false`.

Comment: Oh!I see.I understand.I will try it.

Comment: I added this as an answer, if this works, you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise the UIBarButtonItem with a UIButton as its custom view, and set the the button's adjustsImageWhenHighlighted property to false.